# How do extract information between a beginning index and an ending index

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm using regex to extract the beginning index and ending index of a link from an html file. The indexes come from a string which represents the whole file. How can I extract the link between the beginning index and the ending index?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: I just saw that it is dagged with VB.NET. You can use the String.Substring() method then:

```
 Dim startIndex As Integer = 0
 Dim endIndex As Integer = 10
 Dim s As String = "Hello, this is an example. You can use string.Substring() for this."
 s.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex + 1)
```

For the full documentation, [you can go to the MSDN.](http://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.string.substring%28v%3Dvs.110%29.aspx&ei=4xj7U43dPKSW0QXd4oCgDQ&usg=AFQjCNGBG8Ihywzc8Kj0W-vHeZWn7tRheQ&sig2=RzjSQzaBCTLwGKiwT_rVJw&bvm=bv.73612305,d.bGE&cad=rja)

Comment: I'm using vb.net but thanks. I'll use substring with VB and see what happens. I'm a little rusty with VB.

Comment: You'll need to add 1 to the difference between start and end, though.

Comment: Just be sure to use the right indices. VB.NET uses start and length as parameter, not start and end indices.